# how to use function convert_mushu_data in python package wyrm.io

Tags: python, data-analysis

I've been working on a data project. I've come up to use function
`convert_mushu_data` in library [wyrm.io](http://venthur.github.io/wyrm/).

I have read its documentation but still it's not clear how it actually works.

Can someone elaborate on the parameters passed to function and its return value?

Comment: Can you add some code that you need help with?

Comment: i figured it out.thanks for offering help sebastien